# Issue of page width with twenty fourteen theme

Tags: plugins

I have a site www.mathcounterexamples.net based on Twenty Fourteen theme. I use heavily Mathjax-Latex. For some menus, like Topology, the page width is OK on an iPad, see picture:

[image: picture of Topology menu]

For other menus like Analysis, the page width is shrink compared to the width of the screen, see other picture:

[image: picture of Analysis menu].

You can see that the background image can be seen because the site width is smaller than the iPad screen width.

This appeared only a week before.

Do you have a clue of what can be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you mean? I'm having difficulties understanding your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help! I just added pictures to better document my issue.

Comment: Have you tried to disable all plugins to identify the reason?

Comment: I disabled the plug-ins. The issue is less visible,  I mean that the site shrink less, but still exists. I suspect it started when I upgraded to WP latest version but I'm not sure.